# What might be the correct learning route for a junior developer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I ask for this because I need to use SharePoint on my job, for internal problems and bring solutions to other companies with SharePoint or create new SharePoint sites to solve their problems

But, what must learn first a newbie to develop profesional solutions with SharePoint? I mean, about SharePoint, i know a little of WorkFlows of SharePoint Designer, about CSOM, create forms with SharePoint Designer and couple of things that i don't remember, but they are basic things.

In the other hand, about non SharePoint things, i know about Web Developing in Asp.Net (MVC and Rest API) and Deep learning, I would like to use those abilities in Sharepoint, there any form to integrate both to Sharepoint?

Besides, SharePoint is so bigger than I thought, and there is so many features that I don't know how to use, f.e. the development of SharePoint apps (Those you install on a website)

So, in conclusion, aside from the first question and back to the question on the title, but extending a little more:

What might be the exact "correct" way to learn about Sharepoint on the subject of developing profesional solutions?

Thanks in advance, guys; and I already know, maybe there is too much questions, but, I need a better north to improve in this plataform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of SharePoint. You are on the right track am I am sure you will shine in your SharePointing career. As you said that you already know about how to customize the SharePoint using CSOM, workflow, etc and you are well versed in Asp.net, MVC, REST API and other dot net related stuff. And SharePoint is built on .net framework - you have a solid background of dot net and some knowledge on SharePoint - then you have a good combination - it will help you in the long run.

There are major versions of SharePoint - SharePoint On-Premise and SharePoint Online. In both the core concept of SharePoint and purpose is the same - i.e - collaborative way document management, of course, we could do many other things in SharePoint but document management is the core purpose.

Understand the below concepts of SharePoint:

- What is SharePoint farm
- How do multiple servers get connected with each other, then what is the role of each server?
- What is a web application - how does it handle the web request?
- When to use site collection, when to use the subsite.
- How to handle the custom column through the content type.
- Various types of lists - like a document library, custom list, etc. in which scenario what type of list we should use.
- Understand the various feature in site collection level and site level - what is the concept of those.
- **How to handle the permission in SharePoint in granular level (like from the bottom object like an individual list item, folder, list /library/, site/ site collection, etc.  - it is very important**.

**Notes**

- From the above top, three are related to SharePoint on-premise - rest all common for both the on-premise and SharePoint Online.
- Once your core concept of above each SharePoint object is clear - you can easily customize them using any of the coding techniques like - REST API, CSOM, Workflow, JSOM, SPFX, etc - and your dot net background is plus point.
- Try to create a trial office 365 account and play around on the SharePoint part, mainly PowerApps, PowerAutomate (Microsoft Flow), and some sort Azure connectivity from SharePoint online to Azure and Vice versa.
- Once you are confident about these core concepts - you can propose any type of business solution to the customer based on the scenario and needs. **It is not mandatory one should be good enough to write the code while proposing the solution.**, most of the customers prefer code less solution - plug and play configurable.
- As you mentioned - you are a bit worried about the custom app development as you don't have knowledge on it - no, problem - as mentioned in very few scenarios people go with a hardcore code-based solution - most of the business-related apps is easily configurable from the app store - and many customs apps are available in the GitHub - in that case, we need to have basic knowledge of SharePoint SPFx framework - so that we can customize as per our needs.
- As SharePoint is a vast topic, once you start, you will get an idea and where and how to move.

**Where we can find the resources to learn?**

- Youtube is the best media to learn any new technology and also in google a lot of resources are available.
- You may register in the pluralsight site for the SharePoint course.

You can download the SharePoint Online & Office 365 Administration free eBook from here:

[Free download SharePoint Online & Office 365 Administration ebook pdf](https://global-sharepoint.com/free-download-sharepoint-online-office-365-administration-ebook-pdf/)

All the best, happy learning :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Can you say some basic ideas to develop in SharePoint?

Comment: Hi - SharePoint is not like Asp. Net development project, first we create a site, list library etc.. then we can store data to the list library... then when it comes to development, we customize the SharePoint objects site, list library.. and manipulate the data in the form of webparts, workflow etc. In sp on premises we can write c# code,js, rest api and in sp online we can customize using SPFx framework if it is modern sp, however in classic sp we can write js, rest api, jsom coding... actually SharePoint is a vast, once u start, u will get idea and where and how to move :-)